# Django update user is_active to True in a view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a django view as follows:

```
@staff_member_required
def approve(request, pk):

    prnt = Parent.objects.get(id=pk)
    prnt.request_status = 'A'
    prnt.user.is_active = True

    prnt.save()
```

The view updates every field except the `is_active` field. Here User has OneToOne relationship with the Parent model. Where is the issue? the console doesn't throw any errors either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save the `user` object manually:

```
prnt = Parent.objects.get(id=pk)
prnt.request_status = 'A'
prnt.user.is_active = True
prnt.user.save()  # <---- here
prnt.save()
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this saved my butt. I went to do something like `all_users.update(is_active=False)` on my sandbox database, however, I was accidentally connected to the production database. I was a bit confused as to why it didn't deactivate every single user. But I was grateful.